# Kinect Gesture Recognition: Reset, Recovering and Accuracy

Tags: c#, api, kinect, gesture

In a program I've developped a gesture recognition framework close to [this article](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/A-Simple-Gesture-Processing-Framework-for-the-Kinect-For-Windows).

But I have false positive when I sat in front of the computer. The kinect loose track of Skeleton, then use wrong data.

1) I tried to filter this behavior:

```
return sk.Joints[JointType.Head].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked
       && sk.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].TrackingState  == JointTrackingState.Tracked
       && sk.Joints[JointType.WristRight].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked
       && sk.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].TrackingState    == JointTrackingState.Tracked
       && sk.Joints[JointType.HipRight].TrackingState   == JointTrackingState.Tracked;
```

But even if my Joints are not visible. The Kinect guess and track wrong skeleton !

2) I also try to play with [TransformSmoothParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131024.aspx) but nothing change (don't know best parameters).

3) I also read, Kinect [need to recover](http://carlfranklin.net/blog/2012/4/30/recovering-gracefully-from-loss-of-skeletal-tracking-kinect.html) after skeletal tracking lost. But I don't know how to detect that ? In fact I get many find/lost values which works fine In normal case but trigger false positive when I'm front of PC.

**Is there a Smart way to detect Skeleton is completly wrong even if it is in tracked state ?**

Comment: When too close, the X,Y,Z are completly wrong

Comment: How far away from the computer are you

Comment: In addition to @Kinected question, are you using a Kinect for Xbox 360 or a Kinect for Windows?  If a Kinect for Windows, are you in "Near Mode"?

Comment: I'm using Kinect XBox360 (and so I do not activate NearMode). I'm about 80cm from Kinect and it says 2M. I think it should at least say JointTrackingState.Infered. I'll have to use the depth frame to check that :-(

Comment: @Jean Well you are resetting the values in your return statement, but before you do that are the joints `Tracked`

Comment: @Kinected Yes they are, that's why my sample code didn't work. I thought the API should at least say Infered. For me it's a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I find a better way:

```
  bool track = sk.Joints[JointType.Head].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked
            && sk.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked
            && sk.Joints[JointType.WristRight].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked
            && sk.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked
            && sk.Joints[JointType.HipRight].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked;

  if (track) {
    var head   = sk.Joints[JointType.Head].Position;
    var kludge = sk.Joints[JointType.FootLeft].Position;
    var diff = Math.Abs(head.Y - kludge.Y) * 100;
    track = diff > 80;
  }
```

If distance between foot and head is completly false I assume the skeleton is buggy

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent miss match with Skeleton Stream when API loose track of Skeleton is to use Depth Sensor.

```
var head   = sk.Joints[JointType.Head].Position;
var color  = Sensor.MapSkeletonPointToColor(head, ColorFormat);
var depth1 = Sensor.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(head, DepthFormat);
var depth2 = DepthPixels[color.X + color.Y * DepthW];
```

At last,

1. depth1 is equal to head.Z (I assume algorithm do only a x 1000)
2. depth2 is more accurate and can be 0

See logs:

```
Skeleton: 1,259978 Depth1: 1260 Depth2: 0
Skeleton: 1,259845 Depth1: 1260 Depth2: 0
Skeleton: 1,259783 Depth1: 1260 Depth2: 0
Skeleton: 1,259672 Depth1: 1260 Depth2: 0
Skeleton: 1,259808 Depth1: 1260 Depth2: 0
Skeleton: 1,256333 Depth1: 1256 Depth2: 1221
Skeleton: 1,25608 Depth1: 1256 Depth2: 1216
Skeleton: 1,255606 Depth1: 1256 Depth2: 1216
Skeleton: 1,24086 Depth1: 1241 Depth2: 0
Skeleton: 1,236984 Depth1: 1237 Depth2: 735
Skeleton: 1,233512 Depth1: 1234 Depth2: 725
```

Because sometimes it says 1221, I will also have to ignore everything under depthFrame.MinDepth + X (for me MinDepth = 800)

But sometimes it is still mad:

```
Skeleton: 2,898029 Depth1: 2898 Depth2: 3528 Min: 800
Skeleton: 2,901603 Depth1: 2902 Depth2: 3565 Min: 800
Skeleton: 2,902839 Depth1: 2903 Depth2: 3528 Min: 800
```

Comment: Don't know if there is a more straight forward algorithm to find depth of Head using Depth Stream only

Comment: Because Skeleton and Depth share the same data this answer is not accurate enought.